# Detect which antigen binds to IgE

Tags: molecular-biology, antibody, antigen

Assume that a patient has chronic hives (itchy) on the skin. I understand that he has an antigen, which binds to IgE and eventually triggers histamine release, causing an allergic reaction. So is there any method to detect which molecule/antigen has bound to his IgE? (can we capture it with like what we do to obtain a 3d protein/molecule structure?)

Comment: Have you any idea how much work is involved in determining 3D structures?

Comment: @David I've seen some method to determining 3D structures here but i haven't tried it my self ( I'm just a student learning theory ): https://pdb101.rcsb.org/learn/guide-to-understanding-pdb-data/methods-for-determining-structure. - "The protein is purified, placed in a strong magnetic field," I'm not sure how many copy of purified protein is needed to determine their structure. Is that possible if I extract these IgE-antigen complex from 5cc blood, purify and determine 3d structure like that?

Comment: 3D structure determination is a complex expensive specialized procedure that can take months or years. It is not something that can be performed routinely or even purchased commercially. Labs that do this kind of work choose the proteins to work on with great care because of this, the main criterion being biological interest. They live by their resulting publications.

Comment: @David  I've never known about that. Thank you very much for this precious information. So this mission is very hard to archive even it may possible in theory. I hope to see a method that widely available on the market on near future.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand most allergies are detected by a scratch test. from the link below:

"A skin prick test, also called a puncture or scratch test, checks for immediate allergic reactions to as many as 40 different substances at once. ... After cleaning the test site with alcohol, the nurse draws small marks on your skin and applies a drop of allergen extract next to each mark. He or she then uses a lancet to prick the extracts into the skin's surface. A new lancet is used for each allergen. ...About 15 minutes after the skin pricks, the nurse observes your skin for signs of allergic reactions. If you are allergic to one of the substances tested, you'll develop a raised, red, itchy bump (wheal) that may look like a mosquito bite"

More information on scratch tests can be found here:

http://www.mayoclinic.org/tests-procedures/allergy-tests/basics/what-you-can-expect/prc-20014505

After a quick google search,I found a paper from 2014 [1] that seems to speak to the essence of what you are asking, link below.

http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1586/14737159.4.4.539 [1]

In the paper above they propose using a protein microarray technology to find allergies.

I am not sure if there is any way to extract the igE-antigen complex from the patient. But I think it could probably be done with the microarray technology. Although it would be cool to see a picture of the complex. 
I hope I have helped answer your question.

[1] Harwanegg, Christian, and Reinhard Hiller. "Expert Review of Molecular Diagnostics." Taylor and Francis Online. Expert Review of Molecular Diagnostics, 09 Jan. 2014.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge. +1 for this answer because your answer covered the only possible method that I've known to predict antigen by skin prick test and microarray. But i won't mark this question as resolved because I would like to see a better method, what happen if an unknown antigen present on our body that skin prick test and microarray cannot recognize it?